# How to know after post the form data into codeigniter controller to know form values are shown

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

How to know after post the form data into codeigniter controller to know form values are shown, the data is not showing on the controller

```
 <script>
                $('#login_form').submit(function (e)
                {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var uname = $('#uname').val();
                    var upassword = $('#upassword').val();
                    if (uname == "" || upassword == "")
                    {
                        $('#error').show().html('All Fields are required');
                    } 
                    else {
                        $('#error').html("").hide();
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "<?= base_url(); ?>User_controller/success/",
                            data: {uname: uname, upassword: upassword},
                            datatype: 'script'

                        });
                    }
                    }

            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer shows how to check that the expected inputs are received. If there is some other kind of check you want to make you'll need to edit your answer and explain.

Because you set the ajax option `dataType: 'script',` it is assumed you want to return javascript. (Note: you use `datatype` where it should be `dataType` - the option name is case sensitive.) The "script" I show below serves only as a place holder.

Test for the presence of your inputs using empty(). If a `input->post('item')` is not found CI v2+ and CI v3+ returns different data types - FALSE (boolean) and NULL respectively. The `empty()` function will work for both.

```
function success()
{
   $name = $this->input->post('uname');
   $password = $this->input->post('upassword'); 

   if( empty($name) || empty($password) )
   {
      echo "var result = 'fail';";
   } 
   else
   {
     echo "your javascript code here";
   }
```

You might want to `trim` the fields values either before posting them or within `success()` just to make sure the user didn't send a string full of space characters.

Answer (score 1):

For my Codeigniter App, i have a nice little helper function to clean up the fetching of Variables from the input class.

```
function LoadPostVariables($var_array, $soft_load=false){
    $CI = &get_instance();
    $variables = []
    foreach($var_array as $var){
        if(!is_null($this->input->post($var)){
            $variables[$var] = $CI->input->post($var);
        }else{
            if($soft_load==true){
                $variables[$var] = '';
            }
        }
    }
    return $variables
}
```

which can then be called like so:

```
$login = LoadPostVariables(['username', 'password']);
```

can then use

```
if(!isset($login['username']) || !isset($login['password'])){
    echo "what ever";
}
```

point is, it gives you a central point to check for malicious scripts, and be able to strip inputs and escape them before you work with them. Also if you have a high volume of post variables, its just nice to be able to fetch them all in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function success in your User_controller

```
function success()
{
   $uname = $this->input->post('uname');
   $upasswoed = $this->input->post('upassword'); 
   ...
```

for ajax function you can return values by printing them using `echo`